# Como compartilhar informações do meu site com outro?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho 2 sites, o primeiro que tem as informações e o segundo que quer pegar essas informações, que no caso seriam uma espécie de artigos.

Os artigos contém título,  imagem,  descrição,  tags, data de publicação,  informações do autor (nome,  nome de usuário, imagem do perfil) e vários outros campos.

A minha dúvida é como posso compartilhar essas informações de forma segura e que apenas esse meu segundo site possa ter acesso? Em PHP, Javascript/jQuery

## Edição

Obs: Eu gostaria de pegar apenas os dados, algo parecido com json

Exemplo:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Título do artigo",
        "image": "http://...."
        ......
     },
     {
        "title": "Título do artigo 2",
        "image": "http://...."
        ......
     }
]
```

Comment: na verdade se vai compartilhar a base de dados?

Comment: Não, eu quero apenas informações limitadas sobre os artigos de forma segura em que apenas o segundo site possa ter acesso

Comment: Vc pode fazer um feed XML em um site e puxar as informações no outro.

Answer (score 1):

Se o 2°site for uma única pagina usa em php usa tipo:

```
<form action="Para o 2°Site.php" method="POST">

<p></p>Login:<input type="text" name="Login"></p>
<p>Senha:<input type="password" name="Senha"></p>

<p><input type="submit" align="center" value="Entrar"> | <input type="reset" value="Limpar"></p>


</form>
```

E no outro site usa um php para receber:

```
<?php

$Login = $_POST["Login"];
$Senha = $_POST["Senha"];

print "Bem Vindo ".$Login;

?>
```

Só arrumar o código e implementar no seus 2 sites o  vai no site que vai enviar e o  no 2 que vai receber.

Caso for mais de 1 pagina já não tenho certeza de como se faz.

E tenta trocar o `action="Para o 2°Site.php"` para .html se o seu 2° site for em html.

Comment: Um de nós 2 não entendemos a questão.. Acho que sua interpretação é errônea...

Comment: ata entendi agora oque ele quer fazer minha resposta esta errada então, pensei que ele queria enviar tipo um formulário de login ou alguma coisa do tipo.

Comment: Mesmo assim,  muito obrigado pela resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Sim, você precisa de um site/servidor para gerar a informação, e outro pra ler a resposta. (Acho que entendi o propósito).

Caso seja, você teria que criar requisitações, por um GET no outro servidor, ele te retorna um JSON.
Para limitar o acesso usariamos .htaccess, como limitador de conexões IPs distintos. Não sei se funcionaria SERVER to SERVER, igual ao uso do cliente, mas pode ser uma alternativa simples.
(Há diversas formas, até criar um padrão de segurança TOKEN assim como nos webservices comuns).

Na prática:
A geração de dados teria que haver seu gatilho, no caso uma requisição GET.
www.seuservidor.com/suaURLnaoAmigavel.php?gatilho=SEUS_PARAMETROS

```
if(isset($_GET['gatilho'])){ 
     $abc = array();
     $abc[]['title']=$valor;
     $abc[]['image']=$valor2;
     echo json_encode($abc).
}
```

No final, usaria a função PHP `json_encode($abc)`;

**Exemplo de Output:**

```
 [
{
    "title": "Título do artigo",
    "image": "http://...."
    ......
 },
 {
    "title": "Título do artigo 2",
    "image": "http://...."
    ......
 }
 ]
```

Agora vamos ao JQuery, com o processamento da resposta.

```
$.ajax({
   url:'www.seuservidor.com/suaURLnaoAmigavel.php?gatilho=SEUS_PARAMETROS',
   cache:false,
   method:'GET',       
   success:function(d){
     d=JSON.stringify(eval("(" + d + ")"));
     d=(JSON.parse(d));
     for(var inf=0;inf<=d.length;inf++){
         $('#ondevcquiser').append(d[inf]['title']);
     }
   }
});
```

Lembrando que apenas te dei o código bem genérico, você vai ter que trabalhar em cima se realmente tiver te ajudado.

Boa sorte, espero tê-lo ajudado!